# Change one property of object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I need to loop through `object` and change exactly one of its non-`true` properties to `true`.

```
var object = {a: true, b: false, c: false, d: false}

function changeOne(object) {
  for(var i in object) {
    if(object[i] !== true) {
      object[i] = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This seems like a really bad way to go about this. Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: you way is fine, don't let others confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually fine just that the key order of objects is not defined, so your code might set `b` or `c` or `d` depending on the browsers engine (very unlikely that its not `b` but you never know...), so you should give an order by yourself:

```
 function changeOne(object) {
   for(var key of ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) {
     if(object[key] !== true) {
       object[key] = true;
       break;
     }
   }
 }
```

If you meant "better" in the sense of "shorter":

```
 const changeOne = obj => ["a", "b", "c", "d"].some(key => (obj[key] !== true) && (obj[key] = true));
```

Comment: does key order even matter to OP? why hard-code object props, OP said they were unpredictable...

Comment: @dandavus no, OP said he doesnt know which proerty exactly is going to change. And yes, keyorder matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the entries of the object and use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for a short circuit after a changed property.

```js
function setToTrue(object) {
    Object.entries(object).every(([k, v]) => v || !(object[k] = true));
    return object;
}

var object = { a: true, b: false, c: false, d: false };

console.log(setToTrue(object));
console.log(setToTrue(object));
console.log(setToTrue(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the keys and modify the first one that has a `false` value:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[key] !== true) {
        obj[key] = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{ a: true, b: true, c: false, d: false }
```

**Explanation**

`Object.keys(obj)` will get an array of properties defined on the object itself, while `var i in object` will return additional properties which are part of the prototype. An alternative would be to add a check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`.

Comment: Do you really think `return` will work here as you expect?

Comment: "No" would've been more concise

Comment: @snazzybouche I don't understand your comment, care to explain?

Comment: @alfasin I asked "Is there a better way of doing this" and your answer is essentially a duplicate of the code in my question - if you could explain why the slight differences in yours make it better, that would be ideal, but otherwise it's pretty much the same

Comment: @snazzybouche I just did

Comment: But arent all the object prototypes props not enumerable?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @JonasW. you're right, but I still don't understand your point

Comment: *the object itself, while var i in object will return additional properties which are part of the prototype* there are none in this case, so your code and the OPs do exactly the same.

Comment: this seems like a slow (extra array) convoluted way of doing hasOwnProperty without backwards compat, and OP said nothing about mutated protos, which i haven't seen in the wild since JSON took off...

Comment: @dandavis harsh words... do you have a benchmark that shows that running `hasOwnProperty` on each key is so much more performant than calling `Object.keys`? Second, I *did* mention in the answer the option of using `hasOwnProperty`.